# I am getting an issue while running Tensorflow library from python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

Could not load `cudart64_80.dll`. The GPU version of TensorFlow requires that this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment variable. Download and install CUDA 8.0 from this URL: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit

Comment: Please add more details about what are you exactly trying to do and what did you try to solve the problem.

Comment: I am trying to run python script given by Tensorflow for image classification.Actually i want to research on Object Identification using machine learning algorithms.

Comment: Did you try to install cuda as the error says?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also got the similar issue, and fixed it by downloading CUDA 8.0: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive. I also visited https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit and downloaded CUBA 9.0, but it didn't work. Hence, only CUDA 8.0 works.

Ref: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1024550/download-and-install-cuda-8-0-instead-of-cuda-9-0/